# google.visualization.query - filter spreadsheet data column based on a json.parse parameter

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have 2 google webapps.
First one contains 2 textboxes where users insert username and password. If accepted, these informations pass to the 2nd app url.
The 2nd app extracts with google.visualization.query, data from a google spreadsheet. I can use select and where query without problems with fixed values like strings or numbers but I can't use informations cointained in app url.
My intention is to query my spreadsheet based on mail address contained in app url, so I can show to users only their own data.
Below the script in my html file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script>

google.load('visualization', '1.0', {packages: ['corechart','table']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(loadEditor);


  function loadEditor() {
    var queryString = encodeURIComponent("select A, T where T="");
    var SSID = "xxxxxxxxxMPgJx3gQ" //My spreadsheet ID
    var SHEET_NAME = "FOGLIO ORE"  
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key='+SSID+'&sheet='+SHEET_NAME+'&oauth_token=<?=ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()?>&headers=1&tq=' + queryString);
    query.send(handleSampleDataQueryResponse);
  }


  function handleSampleDataQueryResponse(response) {
    console.log(response);
    var data = response.getDataTable();
    var chartTbl = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('dataTable'));
    chartTbl.draw(data);
  }



</script>
```

Here is the doGet:

```
function doGet(request) {

var params = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(request));
var uname = params.parameter.username;
var email = params.parameter.email;
var imgUrl = params.parameter.imgUrl;
var default_imgUrl = "https://www.pngfind.com/pngs/m/381-3819326_default- 
avatar-svg-png-icon-free-download-avatar.png";
var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('HTML').evaluate().getContent();
html = html.replace(default_imgUrl, imgUrl);
html = html.replace('<a id="user_name">User Name</a>','<a id="user_name">' + 
uname + '</a>');
html = html.replace('<a id="email">email</a>','<a id="email">' + email + 
'</a>');
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
.setTitle('PRESENZE | ' + uname);
output.token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(); 

};
```

Comment: Can you provide your doGet() function?

Comment: Sorry, I think I've post the answer in the wrong way . I've answered to my self...

Comment: Thanks for the function. I'm not sure what you mean by `I can't use informations cointained in app url`, where are you extracting the information from the sheet?

Comment: When user compile text boxes in the first app and click a button, a second app open with url like this: https://script.google.com/a/macros/polo9.org/s/AKfycbzb8v76INTWy9sXT97YtjDe8Oyhno6xxxxxxxxxxxxkmZErYJAiGYvErGw1_jX6i/exec?username=myusername&email=mymail@mymail.org

I want to use the email showed in the url to filter data in the spreadsheet.

Comment: That looks correct, what’s happening in the web app? Also, Is there a reason you have `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(request))`? Seems like you can just reference the parameters directly: `uname = request.parameter.username` etc

Comment: In the web app I can show data in html table format. I can also set query with
"var queryString = encodeURIComponent("select A, T where T="email@myemail.org");" if I set manually the email value to search in column "T".
But I want to insert in my query the email parameter so that each user can see only data contains his email.
I don't know how to obtain e query string using parameter.

Comment: Where do you have the line `var queryString = encodeURIComponent("select A, T where T="email@myemail.org")`?

Comment: In function loadEditor(), in a <div> of the html file under <script> tag.
Thanks for your patience...

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you need to connect to your sheet from the doGet and filter out the results you want based on the url parameters included. Can you provide a sample sheet?

Comment: Exactly, below a sample of the sheet I want to refer to.
In my web app page, I need a simple html table showing only rows that, in column G, contain same email address I have in the url parameters.


https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uTPf4kPEiH3pzAWllVrq2q7RQEPOE-6zGcgoOHdEz58/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

### Answer:

*You need to open the spreadsheet using `SpreadsheetApp().openById()` to extract the information to insert into your HTML table, in a `doGet()` function after publishing the script as a Web App.*

#### Example:

In this example I'll use a Spreadsheet which looks like the sheet you linked in the comments:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Employee** | **Date** | **In** | **Out** | **Type** | **Place** | **Email** |
| **2** | John G. | 21/04/2021 | 9.00 | 12.00 | holidays | Ancona | john.g@mymail.org |
| **3** | Neil Geiman | 22/04/2021 | 9.00 | 15.00 | work | Pesaro | neil.geiman@mymail.org |
| **4** | Penny Lane | 23/04/2021 | 9.00 | 15.00 | holidays | Ancona | penny.lane@mymail.org |
| **5** | Buddy Holly | 24/04/2021 | 9.00 | 15.00 | work | Pesaro | buddy.holly@mymail.org |
| **6** | Neil Geiman | 22/04/2021 | 8.00 | 15.00 | work | Ancona | neil.geiman@mymail.org |
| **7** | Penny Lane | 27/04/2021 | 12.00 | 15.00 | work | Pesaro | penny.lane@mymail.org |

In the `doGet()` function, you will want to use the event object to extract the parameters sent in the URL, as you are already doing:

```
function doGet(e) {
  const uname = params.parameter.username
  const email = params.parameter.email
  const imgUrl = params.parameter.imgUrl
  // ...
}
```

You will then need to open the Spreadsheet with the data programmatically to extract the data:

```
  // ...
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxx")
  // ...
```

You will need to replace the `xxxxxxx` with the ID of the Spreadsheet.

From here, knowing the columns, you can extract out the information you need:

```
  // ...
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Hours sheet") // use actual sheet name
  const emailColumn = 7 // column G = column 7
  const range = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  // ...
```

and then filter the rows you want based on the email parameter you were passed:

```
  // ...
  const rows = [] // initialise an array to store the correct rows
  for (let i = 1; i < range.length: i++) { // start from one to skip the header
    if (range[i][emailColumn] == e.parameter.email) {
      rows.push(range[i])
    }
  }

  console.log(rows)
  // ...
```

So here you will log all the rows as a 2D array which have an email corresponding to the one in the parameter. For the above sheet, using `email=penny.lane@mymail.org` as a URL parameter will log the following:

```
[
  ["Penny Lane", "23/04/2021", "9.00", "15.00", "holidays", "Ancona", "penny.lane@mymail.org"],
  ["Penny Lane", "27/04/2021", "12.00", "15.00", "work", "Pesaro", "penny.lane@mymail.org"]
]
```

Which you can use to form your HTML table.

#### References:

- [Class SpreadsheetApp | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [Web Apps | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

Comment: Sorry, I can't log desired rows. I obtain: [ ] in the log.
I've tried to debug my function, it shows - range: array (10734) and rows: array (0).